# Missing content in Pages only

Tags: the-content, content

I have an odd one.

One site is missing all content on it's page (but not posts.)

If I add a filter on 'the_content', `$content` is empty.  I've tried giving the filter priority of 1, 0 and even negative numbers to make sure an earlier filter isn't screwing it up.

The contents of `$post->post_content` is as it should be.

I've disabled all plugins, (including mu-plugins) switched to twentyseventeen theme, and still no content.

I'm starting to lose sleep over this one.

Any suggestions as to where I should be looking next?